# Why does Windows 7 unload keyboard and mouse drivers all the time? How can I prevent it?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a KVM hooked up to two computers, one of which is running Windows 7.  Every time I switch away from it and switch back, there's a delay while it reloads the drivers for the keyboard and mouse.  This constantly interrupts whatever I'm trying to do, not just my actions but my flow of thought, and therefore does far more harm than just rob me of a few seconds many times per day.

Is there any way to prevent this?  Any way to make Windows keep the drivers loaded all the time?

Comment: Which KVM are you using? Do you have another Win7 device you could use the KVM on that would allow you to determine if the issue if with that specific computer or with multiple?

Comment: I don't know an answer but wanted to chime in and say that I have had this problem before too. My solution was to ditch the KVM and go with a virtual KVM instead. Not really a solution or answer, more of a workaround though.

Comment: I also use Synergy, but it frequently fails, which is one reason I still use the hardware KVM.  Also, it can't handle an external monitor shared between two laptops, which a real KVM can handle.

Comment: I don't have another Windows 7 device, but the other computer I use doesn't have this problem ever.